# How to call a partial view through ajax in MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I am developing an application in MVC3
I need to show a partail view on click of a dropdown
For that i wrote an ajax,

```
 $("#UserName").change(function () {
        var userid = $("#UserName").val();
        var ProvincialStateID = $("#State").val();
        var Hobbyid = $("#Hobby").val();
        var Districtid = $("#DistrictNames").val();
        var Homeid = $("#Hobbyhome_EstablishmentId").val();
        var urlperson = '@Url.Action("FetchPersonByUserName")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlperson,
            data: { userid: userid, stateid: ProvincialStateID, hobbyid: Hobbyid, districtid: Districtid, homeid: Homeid },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
```

and i wrote a function in controller as:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FetchPersonByUserName(int userid,int stateid,int districtid,int homeid,int Hobbyid)
    {
        //Code to fetch data using all the parameters
        return PartialView("_LearnerAssociationGridPartial", list);
    }
```

From here it goes in the partial view there i can also see the data

But while it comes in the frontend i am not able to see the data.
Please Help me maybe my ajax may be wrong please tell me where i am goin wrong.

this is my Main View:

```
@model HobbyHomesWebApp.ViewModel.LearnerAssociationViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPostLogin.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("LearnerAssociation", "Registration", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     <table>
         <div>
             @{Html.RenderPartial("_LearnerAssociationWebPartial", Model.learner);}
         </div> 
     </table>
     <table>
         <div id="result">
             @{Html.RenderPartial("_LearnerAssociationGridPartial", Model.LearnerList);}
         </div>
     </table>
}
```

The ajax function is written in the first view and the dropdown is in the first view.
Now onclick of dropdown in first view i want the data to be displayed in a grid which is in the second view.

My first View is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LearnerAssociation", "Registration", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Label(@Resources.selectusername)
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Loginaccount.LoginAccountID, new SelectList(ViewBag.UserName, "LoginAccount.LoginAccountID", "FirstName"), "--Select UserName--", new { @id = "UserName" })
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
            </table>
```

}

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the data you get back from the ajax post.

Comment: what are you doing on ajax success ?

Comment: @Saad hey when i debug and go to my partial view their the data is fetched like if i click on the field i can see the data but after debugging completes when the page is displayed it does not show the data on the page.

Comment: @Saad No act i dont need the data back here i jus want to redirect it to the View from my controller function

Comment: means you want a redirect to action ? or want to show the view on the same page?(in any dialog or in div ?)

Comment: @Jonathan Ya i don need the data back i jus want to redirect it to the Partial View i am new toajax function plz do guide abt watevr i swrong in that

Comment: @Saad yes i want to redirect to a partial view which is on the same page

Answer (score 3):

Edit: OK so if I understand correctly, your view should look like this:

```
@model HobbyHomesWebApp.ViewModel.LearnerAssociationViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPostLogin.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("LearnerAssociation", "Registration", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     <table>
         <tr>
         <td>
            <div>
                 @{Html.RenderPartial("_LearnerAssociationWebPartial", Model.learner);}
            </div> 
         </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
         <tr>
         <td> 
             <div id="result">

            </div>
         </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
}
```

This means when you first load the page, nothing is displayed in the second `div`.

You then want to load a partial view in to the `div` based on the value selected. Firstly, add the javascript to call the action you have already described.

```
$('#NameOfYourDropDownList').change(function () {
    var userid = $('#NameOfYourDropDownList').val();
    var ProvincialStateID = $("#State").val();
    var Hobbyid = $('#Hobby').val();
    var Districtid = $('#DistrictNames').val();
    var Homeid = $('#Hobbyhome_EstablishmentId').val();
    var urlperson = "@Url.Action('FetchPersonByUserName')";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlperson,
        data: { userid: userid, stateid: ProvincialStateID, hobbyid: Hobbyid, districtid: Districtid, homeid: Homeid },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The `ActionResult` will return the HTML. In your success function, you are assigning this to be the HTML of the `div`.

Comment: Hey thanx For the answer but i am not getting exactly how shal i apply it..i ahve updaetd my question please have a look at it.

Comment: Can you add the part of the view that contains the dropdownlist you want to use to populate the PartialView?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood what you wanted (don't shoot me if I didn't)

Let's assume for a minute that you have a tag

```
<div id="Returned-Content-Container">
</div>
```

I'll make 2 suggestion (choose what you like)

Razor engine, MVC style:

When you create the form with the code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LearnerAssociation", "Registration", FormMethod.Post))
```

Replace the FormMethod.Post with

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LearnerAssociation", "Registration", 
        new AjaxOptions() 
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "POST",
                                UpdateTargetId = "Returned-Content-Container",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                            })
        {
              // Your form fields go here
        }
```

What this does is upon return of the data it replaces the defined tag with the data returned from the ajax call. Automatically.

This way is to do it with the razor engine.

If you want to do it the jquery way just do the following:

```
$("#UserName").change(function () {
    var userid = $("#UserName").val();
    var ProvincialStateID = $("#State").val();
    var Hobbyid = $("#Hobby").val();
    var Districtid = $("#DistrictNames").val();
    var Homeid = $("#Hobbyhome_EstablishmentId").val();
    var urlperson = '@Url.Action("FetchPersonByUserName")';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlperson,
        data: { userid: userid, stateid: ProvincialStateID, hobbyid: Hobbyid, districtid: Districtid, homeid: Homeid },
        success: function (data) {
             // This places all data returned into the defined DOM element
             $('#Returned-Content-Container').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps,

Good luck !

Comment: hey i tried ur jquery but can u tell me how shall i return the 'data' from the controller function written in 'urlperson' to the ajax function.

Comment: Well basically when you return a partialView it is actually an HTML snippet. This HTML snippet should just be inserted in its appropriate location.